# XSLT: How to implement multi loop element in single XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

We have Input XML. In that, we want to multi loop two tag. Those tags are StockLine and CommentLine. We have to Loop both together in a way. When StockLine is null then CommentLine otherwise when CommentLine is null then StockLine.

In this scenario:
We have total 9 line Items 7 stockLine and 2 CommentLine.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>

-<SalesOrders xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<Orders>


-<OrderHeader>

<CustomerPoNumber>AB-54354</CustomerPoNumber>

<OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>

<Customer>036938</Customer>

<OrderDate>2016-03-07</OrderDate>

<CustomerName>jennifer straight</CustomerName>

<ShipAddress1>5352 shaw st</ShipAddress1>

<ShipAddress3>NEW PORT RICHEY</ShipAddress3>

<ShipAddress4>FL</ShipAddress4>

<ShipAddress5>US</ShipAddress5>

<OrderDiscPercent1>0.0</OrderDiscPercent1>

<RequestedShipDate>2016-03-07</RequestedShipDate>

<SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-436326</SalesForceOrderNumber>

</OrderHeader>


-<OrderDetails>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>LADO-SMO-4OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMO LAVENDER DRY OIL 4OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>7.99</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>1</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1634834</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>WSSB-SMS-6OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMW COCONUT SHAVE BUTTER 6OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>7.99</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>2</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1636755</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHCM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH COCONUT MILK 8OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>0.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>6</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1641836</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHWS-SMO-03</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SPECIAL2 COCONUT HM/CM/CC</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>25.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>4</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1642378</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHHM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH COCONUT HAIR MIST 8OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>0.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>7</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1642587</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHCC-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH CH COWASH CLEANSER 8OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>0.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>5</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1652357</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>ABSH-SMH-12OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH ABS BALANCE SHAMPOO 12OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>10.99</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>3</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1659227</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>8</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1810124</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>9</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1810125</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>
```

-

OR-1634834

```
</OrderDetails>

</Orders>

</SalesOrders>
```

**We tried XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='true']" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CommentLine[OrderLineID = preceding-sibling::StockLine/OrderLineID and not(Comment)]"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>

-<SalesOrders xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<Orders>


-<OrderHeader>

<CustomerPoNumber>AB-54354</CustomerPoNumber>

<OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>

<Customer>036938</Customer>

<OrderDate>2016-03-07</OrderDate>

<CustomerName>jennifer straight</CustomerName>

<ShipAddress1>5352 shaw st</ShipAddress1>

<ShipAddress3>NEW PORT RICHEY</ShipAddress3>

<ShipAddress4>FL</ShipAddress4>

<ShipAddress5>US</ShipAddress5>

<OrderDiscPercent1>0.0</OrderDiscPercent1>

<RequestedShipDate>2016-03-07</RequestedShipDate>

<SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-436326</SalesForceOrderNumber>

</OrderHeader>


-<OrderDetails>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>LADO-SMO-4OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMO LAVENDER DRY OIL 4OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>7.99</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>1</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1634834</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>WSSB-SMS-6OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMW COCONUT SHAVE BUTTER 6OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>7.99</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>2</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1636755</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHCM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH COCONUT MILK 8OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>0.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>6</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1641836</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHWS-SMO-03</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SPECIAL2 COCONUT HM/CM/CC</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>25.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>4</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1642378</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHHM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH COCONUT HAIR MIST 8OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>0.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>7</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1642587</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>CHCC-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH CH COWASH CLEANSER 8OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>0.0</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>5</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1652357</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>


-<StockLine>

<CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>

<StockCode>ABSH-SMH-12OZ-01</StockCode>

<StockDescription>SMH ABS BALANCE SHAMPOO 12OZ</StockDescription>

<OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>

<OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>

<Price>10.99</Price>

<PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>

<AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>

<UserDefined>3</UserDefined>

<OrderLineID>OR-1659227</OrderLineID>

</StockLine>

<CommentLine>
                <Comment>This is for test purpose</Comment>
                <OrderLineID>OR-1810121</OrderLineID>
             </CommentLine>
<CommentLine>
                <Comment>EDI SAVE</Comment>
                <OrderLineID>OR-1810121</OrderLineID>
             </CommentLine>





</OrderDetails>

</Orders>

</SalesOrders>
```

Comment: You've shown your desired output, but not your input.

Comment: @MichaelKay  We have updated the Input . structure is same as output only we heve to repeat StockLine and CommentLine according to if then else condition check.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. How can you get 10 `StockLine` elements in the output when you only have one in the input? I see the `<Quantity>` tag is set to 10, but where does the other information in the output come from?

Comment: @jokab  WE wanted to perform  if then else in expected Output XML

Comment: criteria is :We have Input XML. In that, we want to multi loop two tag. Those tags are StockLine and CommentLine. We have to Loop both together in a way. When StockLine is null then CommentLine otherwise when CommentLine is null then StockLine.

In this scenario: We have total 9 line Items 7 stockLine and 2 CommentLine.

Comment: Yes I read your description, you don't need to paste it in the comments. You need to rephrase your question in order for it to be understandable. There is very little information on how your input is supposed to be transformed into your expected output.

Comment: we want multiple line items.  we want to repeat StockLline and Comment Line  such that When StockLine is null then CommentLine otherwise when CommentLine is null then StockLine.

Comment: @jokab  scenario is basically we have 9 line order Item. 7 for StockLine and 2 for CommentLine .But   USING xslt  we want to repeat StockLline and Comment Line such that When StockLine is null then CommentLine otherwise when CommentLine is null then StockLine

Comment: but this XML IS repeating 9 StockLine itself   but reality is StockLline is only 7 and 2 is CommentLine

Comment: "*We have total 9 line Items 7 stockLine and 2 CommentLine.*"  I see 9 `StockLine` nodes and no `CommentLine`. -- P.S. Please stop repeating the same thing over and over. To make your question clearer, post an example of input that matches your description, and the expected output of transforming the given input.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: If you have at least one element in the input that is `StockLine` then you want to output only the `StockLine` elements. But if you don't have any `StockLine`, you want to output the `CommentLine` elements. Correct?

Comment: @jokab  Yes  . suppose i have 3 stockLine and 2 commentLine  total 5  element should come instead of 5 stockline

Comment: it always check the orderLineID  . if OrderLineID is having Stockline  it should write StockLine if OrderLine ID has CommentLine it should write CommentLine

Comment: each OrderLineID associated with  either  StockLine or CommentLine.

Comment: Where in the input is the value "This is for test purpose" that appears in the output?!

Comment: That isn't what I suggested... If you have three `StockLine` and two `CommentLine` then you want five elements? Three of those five should be `StockLine`, what are the other two? Also about the `OrderLineID`, how do you know if it signifies a `StockLine` or a `CommentLine`? This is all very unclear.

Comment: @Jokab    Your suggested is we want.

Comment: @michael.hor257k   input value that you are asking is not in  InputXML . Because it is replacing by Stockline.

Comment: @vickps I have no idea what "*it is replacing by Stockline*' means. An XSLT stylesheet transforms the given input. It cannot make up values on its own.

Comment: @vickps I am sorry but you are making very little sense. Where do the values in the output `CommentLine` elements come from? They do not appear in the input at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="StockLine[not(StockCode)]">
    <CommentLine>
        <Comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="some-unknown-node"/>
        </Comment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="OrderLineID"/>
    </CommentLine>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wasn't able to determine where the value of `Comment` should come from.

Comment: <CommentLine>
                <Comment>This is for test purpose</Comment>
                <OrderLineID>OR-1810121</OrderLineID>
             </CommentLine>

Comment: @vickps Please stop wasting the time of people that are trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry for In convienence